# Valgrind hangs when program run

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am using valgrind for first time. I tried running it by instructions I saw by just giving it the name of my program. Then later I used the `--leak-check=full` option. But either way it only gives me a few lines describing what it does, it seems to be hanging not sure if normal so after a while I do ctrl + c and it shows more information. 
I don't think this is normal usage of the program, so i'd like to know what is going on. Is there any another command i need after i start it to show the information? Or is the program really doing something? Maybe i'll try letting hang there but if it's that slow it's kinda useless, this program is very small.

Comment: Not sure how small your program is. But running it with valgrind will be slower than normal.

Comment: You prefix the program you want to monitor with `valgrind` (so, for example, `valgrind -- ./new-program 11 13 97`, where the double-dash is optional but separates `valgrind` arguments from program arguments). It then runs, outputting some header information, then whatever output the program normally gives, then some summary information as the program ends.  If the program reads from standard input, you still have to provide it with the input.  So, what is your program doing?  What would happen if you simply ran `./new-program`?  That's what should happen if you run `valgrind ./new-program`.

Comment: If your program seems to hang under Valgrind, you can investigate what is happening either from the shell (using the command 'vgdb v.info scheduler')  or using gdb+vgdb (see http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more info)

Comment: Ouch, it does indead read from stdin! It's working fine now, and it's not slow at all. Thanks.

Comment: @phd, the vgdb.v.info tip was very helpful to me. That should be an answer.

Comment: For future readers, I second what @jayant said. The delay can be relatively significant. My program originally ran for 1 minute, but with valgrind its run time extended to 20 minutes.